# Return calculation from a class based on hard coded value and property value

Tags: c#, properties

How can I return the calculated value _B where one of the arguments is value _A and hard coded data for example "1" ?

```
class Example
{
    private static int _A;
    private static int _B = _A + 1;

    public int GetA
    {
        get
        {
            return _A;
        }
        set
        {
            _A = value;
        }
    }

    public int GetB
    {
        get
        {
            return _B;
        }
    }
}
```

I`m always getting back just "1".

```
Example example = new Example();
example.GetA = 20; // set { }          
Console.WriteLine(example.GetB); // get { }
```

**I was hoping to get 21.**

Comment: You should set _B in GetA setter. Or replace _B by a property `private static int _B => _A + 1;`

Comment: @Kalten that worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a value to a property in the same line as the declaration, the value is set only one time.

You have at least two options, use new property declaration with arrow function. Or set the value in the setter of the dependent property.

```
class Example
{
    private static int _A;
    private static int GetB => _A + 1;

    public int GetA
    {
        get
        {
            return _A;
        }
        set
        {
            _A = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
class Example
{
    private static int _A;
    private static int _B;

    public int GetA
    {
        get
        {
            return _A;
        }
        set
        {
            _A = value;
            _B = _A + 1;
        }
    }

    public int GetB
    {
        get
        {
            return _B;
        }

    }
}
```